# In swift, how do I only perform a segue after a server has given me a certain response?

Tags: swift, modal-dialog

In swift, how do I only perform a segue after a server has given me a certain response?

I'd like to click a submit button. That will send a request to the server. Then, if the server responds positively, I want a view to be presented modally, otherwise, I want to write a UIAlertView.

I know how to write the UIAlertView and I have the Modal View prepared, I just can't figure out how to write it such that the modal view only presents itself conditionally.

Comment: Please show the code that you have try.

Comment: What will happen in the meantime while the app will be waiting for the response from the server? Can the user use the app and go to a different screen, perhaps dismiss the current controller? Are you disabling / ignoring additional taps on "Submit" button while the network communication is still in progress?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give a segue identifier on your storyboard. Then you can use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

first make a segue between the view controllers and give the segue identifier

```
 eg: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

and when you get the response of the service request and on the basis of that check the status or the valid http status code.

```
eg: if status returns true {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}  

or if statuscode == 200...299 {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your submit button wired up to an `IBAction` you could do something like this...

```
@IBAction func submitClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    //try to hit server
    let serverResponse = server.trySomeFunction()
    if serverResponse {
        //server response was successful!
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    } else {
        //server response failure, present alert
    }
}
```